# django error in python No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a website with django and I get this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\py_website_django>django-admin startproject pyshop
(venv) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\py_website_django>python manage.py runserver


 C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\py_website_django\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create a project folder inside your `py_website_django` folder. `manage.py` will be inside `pyshop` folder not in `py_website_django`.

I suggest you to create your project like this:

```
django-admin startproject pyshop .
```

adding a dot at the end will create the project inside the current directory, also, `manage.py` will be inside your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cd into pyshop and then run the command. thats where manege.py should be

Comment: cd will obviously work, and it's a valid solution, but py_website_django will be an useless extra dir

Comment: py_website_django will be the outer container for the project. see Django docs. That is the standard way of creating a django project.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: py_website_django will be the dir that containts the outer pyshop dir which is the outer container for the project, and the pyshop inside the outer pyshop is the actual Python package for the project. edit: I guess we misunderstood and saying the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
cd pyshop
```

Then do

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score -1):

You know, sometimes it's just a conflicting naming issue you might have

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this: Redo all the configuration from scratch and when typing a command line in the terminal:

```
django-admin startproject 'your project name'
```

ADD A "SPACE" AND A "." the line would be:

```
django-admin startproject 'your project name' .
```

Comment: I've made an [edit] to your answer to add some formatting, as otherwise the syntax was getting lost. Can you review my edit to make sure it's consistent with your intent? If it is, you can let me know via a comment, or flag this comment as _No longer needed_.